# RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT not showing the intended text in Android Wear

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os

In my wearable application i am opening up the speech input screen by passing the custom prompt text but unfortunately it's not showing that text but only "Speak Now" instead.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Say fast");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

This same code snippet works fine in mobile devices and shows the "Say fast" but it's not working on my LG G watch. What can be the possible issue? does anyone have faced the same issue? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I discovered this the other day as well at a bootcamp I was running. We are looking into it, but I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: Can you share by when it will be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on my Samsung Gear Live I've received update to 5.0.1 and can confirm, that this bug is fixed and EXTRA_PROMPT is displayed correctly on recognizer screen